# Form field data history not retained

Tags: html, forms, ssl, https, input

I have a form on a page that is shown via https:// as follows:

```
<form id="memberslogin_form" name="memberslogin_form">
<fieldset>
 <legend>Login</legend>
 <div>
  <label for="membershipId">Membership number</label>
  <input type="text" class="field" name="membershipId" id="membershipId""/>
 </div>
 <div>
  <label for="memberPassword">Password</label>
  <input size="18" type="password" class="field" maxlength="50" name="memberPassword" id="memberPassword" />
 </div>
 <div id="button_login">  
  <input type="button" value="Login" class="button" id="signin" name="signin"/>
 </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

The form is uniquely named, as are the inputs.

However, successful logins do not cause the "membershipId" entries to be listed in the input recent entries \ history. This occurs in both FF3.6 and IE6+.

I believe the ability to store field history is browser-based via it's settings, but I cannot retain the input history over https:// forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a typo in here only, or in actual page:

```
<input type="text" class="field" name="membershipId" id="membershipId""/>
```

See the extra `"`.

I don't know much about the mechanism of saving form value in FF, but all this time, my form input is saved even if it in `https` site.

Maybe you can try [lastpass](https://lastpass.com/) that can save a form input for later usage as well as the password securely.